# Force top margin on flexbox item with unknown height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with two columns, each having dynamic content, which means dynamic height. I need to lower the right column and for that I set a top margin. This does not produce the desired result, as the bottom does not get pushed, it remains aligned with the bottom of the left column (following the specs, which dictate that flex items should, by default, have the same height). [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4qf35ef/2/) for reference.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .component {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*height: 250px;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.container .right {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="component left">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="component right">
    <p>
      Morbi sit amet pharetra turpis, id placerat sem. Fusce tempus nisl vel arcu euismod, nec convallis risus ullamcorper. Duis fringilla molestie lacus nec rhoncus. Nunc ex massa, placerat id risus sed, luctus varius elit. Nam vestibulum orci a massa sollicitudin
      porttitor. Donec sagittis odio metus, eu aliquam tellus blandit eget. Aenean viverra dapibus risus at euismod. Ut hendrerit scelerisque libero, at accumsan ligula vestibulum in. Vivamus tristique erat faucibus ante dapibus vestibulum. Maecenas id
      auctor elit. Nullam at interdum arcu, in gravida nisl. Nunc lacinia, quam a hendrerit auctor, sapien est pulvinar mauris, non laoreet justo elit id risus. Nullam vel nulla ligula. Vestibulum at tincidunt orci, non rhoncus sapien. Vivamus nunc eros,
      tempus a ex non, dictum posuere enim.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need can be achieved with fixed heights, but that's not flexible enough and can't afford the luxury. In the snippet above, uncomment the height of the `.container .component`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .component {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.container .right {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="component left">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="component right">
    <p>
      Morbi sit amet pharetra turpis, id placerat sem. Fusce tempus nisl vel arcu euismod, nec convallis risus ullamcorper. Duis fringilla molestie lacus nec rhoncus. Nunc ex massa, placerat id risus sed, luctus varius elit. Nam vestibulum orci a massa sollicitudin
      porttitor. Donec sagittis odio metus, eu aliquam tellus blandit eget. Aenean viverra dapibus risus at euismod. Ut hendrerit scelerisque libero, at accumsan ligula vestibulum in. Vivamus tristique erat faucibus ante dapibus vestibulum. Maecenas id
      auctor elit. Nullam at interdum arcu, in gravida nisl. Nunc lacinia, quam a hendrerit auctor, sapien est pulvinar mauris, non laoreet justo elit id risus. Nullam vel nulla ligula. Vestibulum at tincidunt orci, non rhoncus sapien. Vivamus nunc eros,
      tempus a ex non, dictum posuere enim.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see in the above example that the both the top and the bottom of the right column have the `20px` offset as a result of setting `margin-top`. Is there a way of achieving this result without explicitly setting the height of the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to add `margin-bottom: 20px` on `.left`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .component {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.container .right {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.container .left {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="component left">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="component right">
    <p>
      Morbi sit amet pharetra turpis, id placerat sem. Fusce tempus nisl vel arcu euismod, nec convallis risus ullamcorper. Duis fringilla molestie lacus nec rhoncus. Nunc ex massa, placerat id risus sed, luctus varius elit. Nam vestibulum orci a massa sollicitudin
      porttitor. Donec sagittis odio metus, eu aliquam tellus blandit eget. Aenean viverra dapibus risus at euismod. Ut hendrerit scelerisque libero, at accumsan ligula vestibulum in. Vivamus tristique erat faucibus ante dapibus vestibulum. Maecenas id
      auctor elit. Nullam at interdum arcu, in gravida nisl. Nunc lacinia, quam a hendrerit auctor, sapien est pulvinar mauris, non laoreet justo elit id risus. Nullam vel nulla ligula. Vestibulum at tincidunt orci, non rhoncus sapien. Vivamus nunc eros,
      tempus a ex non, dictum posuere enim.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Kind of obvious, if you think about it for a second... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using margin, you could use `position: relative;` and `top: 20px;`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red; 
  padding: 10px;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.container .component {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*height: 250px;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.container .right {
  top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="component left">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="component right">
   <p>
    Morbi sit amet pharetra turpis, id placerat sem. Fusce tempus nisl vel arcu euismod, nec convallis risus ullamcorper. Duis fringilla molestie lacus nec rhoncus. Nunc ex massa, placerat id risus sed, luctus varius elit. Nam vestibulum orci a massa sollicitudin porttitor. Donec sagittis odio metus, eu aliquam tellus blandit eget. Aenean viverra dapibus risus at euismod. Ut hendrerit scelerisque libero, at accumsan ligula vestibulum in. Vivamus tristique erat faucibus ante dapibus vestibulum. Maecenas id auctor elit. Nullam at interdum arcu, in gravida nisl. Nunc lacinia, quam a hendrerit auctor, sapien est pulvinar mauris, non laoreet justo elit id risus. Nullam vel nulla ligula. Vestibulum at tincidunt orci, non rhoncus sapien. Vivamus nunc eros, tempus a ex non, dictum posuere enim.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The (obvious) down side of using positioning loosing context and this is visible in your solution, as the bottom of the left column "steps over" the container.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use the align-self Flexbox attribute to essentially set the vertical-align of the component elements. Is this what you're after? Sort of flies in the face of Flexbox a bit!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .component {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*height: 250px;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.container .right {
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.container .left {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="component left">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="component right">
    <p>
      Morbi sit amet pharetra turpis, id placerat sem. Fusce tempus nisl vel arcu euismod, nec convallis risus ullamcorper. Duis fringilla molestie lacus nec rhoncus. Nunc ex massa, placerat id risus sed, luctus varius elit. Nam vestibulum orci a massa sollicitudin
      porttitor. Donec sagittis odio metus, eu aliquam tellus blandit eget. Aenean viverra dapibus risus at euismod. Ut hendrerit scelerisque libero, at accumsan ligula vestibulum in. Vivamus tristique erat faucibus ante dapibus vestibulum. Maecenas id
      auctor elit. Nullam at interdum arcu, in gravida nisl. Nunc lacinia, quam a hendrerit auctor, sapien est pulvinar mauris, non laoreet justo elit id risus. Nullam vel nulla ligula. Vestibulum at tincidunt orci, non rhoncus sapien. Vivamus nunc eros,
      tempus a ex non, dictum posuere enim.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still need the heights of the columns to be equal. The left column, in your solution, looses it's "original" height.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do u need like this?
<!--css -->
<style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .container .component {
      width: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 0px 10px;
      position: relative;

    }
    .container .right {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .container .left {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
</style>



<!--html-->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="component left">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="component right">

 <p>
          Morbi sit amet pharetra turpis, id placerat sem. Fusce tempus nisl vel arcu euismod, nec convallis risus ullamcorper. Duis fringilla molestie lacus nec rhoncus. Nunc ex massa, placerat id risus sed, luctus varius elit. Nam vestibulum orci a massa sollicitudin
          porttitor. Donec sagittis odio metus, eu aliquam tellus blandit eget. Aenean viverra dapibus risus at euismod. Ut hendrerit scelerisque libero, at accumsan ligula vestibulum in. Vivamus tristique erat faucibus ante dapibus vestibulum. Maecenas id
          auctor elit. Nullam at interdum arcu, in gravida nisl. Nunc lacinia, quam a hendrerit auctor, sapien est pulvinar mauris, non laoreet justo elit id risus. Nullam vel nulla ligula. Vestibulum at tincidunt orci, non rhoncus sapien. Vivamus nunc eros,
          tempus a ex non, dictum posuere enim.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```